# Write data from a dstream to parquet

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, pyspark

After consuming data from kinesis using pyspark, I have a dstream with entries like this:

```
('filename_1', [{'name': 'test'}, {'name': 'more'}, {'name': 'other'}])
('filename_2', [{'age': 15}, {'age': 25}])
```

What I want to do now is to write the second part of the tuple to the location identified by the first part of the tuple.

At other places I did that by converting each list of dictionaries to a DataFrame using:

```
dataframe = sqlContext.createDataFrame(list_of_dicts)
```

and writing it with something like:

```
dataframe.write.parquet('filename')
```

My problem is now how to turn every line in the dstream into a DataFrame. My intuition was to use map to get every single line and do the conversion. This would need a sqlContext which you can actually not pass to a map function, as it fails with this error:

```
Exception: It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transforamtion. SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run on workers. For more information, see SPARK-5063
```

I'm not absolutely tied to parquet, but I need some kind of schema (hence the detour to DataFrame). Is there a way to do that with spark?

Answer (score 0):

You can create new instance of SqlContext inside `foreach` method.

```
words.foreachRDD(
  new Function2<JavaRDD<String>, Time, Void>() {
    @Override
    public Void call(JavaRDD<String> rdd, Time time) {
      SQLContext sqlContext = JavaSQLContextSingleton.getInstance(rdd.context());
```

For more detail you can go through this [link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/streaming-programming-guide.html#dataframe-and-sql-operations).

Comment: As far as I understand, each RDD might still consist of multiple lines (at least that's why I think there is the map a bit later in the example you linked to), so I still cannot put a complete RDD into one dataframe as each line should be its own dataframe.

Comment: you can't use sqlContext inside the map. it only works inside foreachRdd function. Have you go through that link?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the problem. Each RDD may still contain more than one row, but as each row is supposed to become one DataFrame I end up with a construct like this:
`for name in names:`

`        filtered = rdd.filter(lambda name_record: filter_by_name(name, name_record))`

`        df = sqlc.createDataFrame(records)`

`        df.write.parquet(OUT_PATH + name, mode='append')`

Which is less than optimal.

Comment: Sorry for the malformated code. I'm not allowed to edit this post anymore, here is the code in a more readable format:
http://codetidy.com/6893/

Comment: Ok so try this, First you get all the rdds from dstream using `foreachRdd` function and then collect all lines as a list from each rdds using `collect function`. now you have all the lines, convert each line to rdd and then create dataframe using that rdd with your custom schema.